# Class log does not exist in Container.php but I have no unquoted spaces in .env or errors in config

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've been stuck trying to figure out why I get this every time I try to run `php artisan key:generate` (or any other `php artisan` command).

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:734
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(734): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
#1 C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(629): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
#2 C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
#3 C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(849): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')
#4 C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(804): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 C:\Users\Sam\P in C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 734

Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:734
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(734): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
#1 C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(629): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
#2 C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
#3 C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(849): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')
#4 C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(804): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 C:\Users\Sam\P in C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 734
```

Some suggested putting this at the top of vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php because it would reveal the underlying error:

```
namespace {
    use Monolog\Logger as Monolog;
    class log extends Illuminate\Log\Writer {
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->monolog = new Monolog("local");
        }
    }
}
```

But instead I started getting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class env does not exist in C:\Users\Sam\PhpstormProjects\banqo.net\vendor\laravel\
framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:744
```

with a similar stacktrace to the initial error. I've been researching online what could be causing it. Someone suggested running 'phpunit', so I did and I got the error:

`Dotenv\Exception\InvalidFileException: Dotenv values containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes.`

I thought this was interesting because people had suggested that .env values containing spaces could have caused the initial problem, but I have thoroughly and repeatedly checked my .env file for spaces and there are none where there shouldn't be. I even tried wrapping literally every single .env value in quotes. On top of all this my IDE (Phpstorm) tells me that there are no errors in any of the files in my config folder.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Have you run `composer install` to install dependencies?

Comment: @Xint0 yes I have, although the postInstall fails because it calls php artisan optimize, which returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1**

Make sure you have installed all packages properly `composer install`.

**STEP 2**

Run `composer dump-autoload` to generate class references again.